# How to retrieve a MySQL value with AJAX on PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Ok, this one is taking me some time now, I've read other topics and cannot seem to solve it.

I have a select populated with a PHP function **article_search()** that retrieves all article names from a the table **article** in my DB

```
<select id="article_select">
    <?php
        $article_group = article_search();
        foreach($article_group as $item) {
            echo "<option value=\"{$item["idArt"]}\">{$item["name"]}</option>";
        }
    ?>  
</select>
```

What I need is, when the user selects an article, an AJAX function search the field **price** from the table **article** in the database and puts the result in this element:

```
<p>Price:
    <input type="text" class="details" id="price" name="price">
</p>
```

Needless to say that I have no experience in AJAX, but it seems like the only solution at these point.

Every bit of help would be appreciated.

Comment: You could output the price in the `option` element in a `data` attribute then have JS update the price element with that value when the option is selected. If the price is updating frequently then using AJAX would make sense. https://learn.jquery.com/ajax/

Comment: Do you want to use Native JS or JQuery?

Comment: @Twisty at this point, anything that works. The central point would be: user selects an article and the price input gets the value of that article, without the need to reload the page or add a button to search the price. I like chris85 idea, but how would JS do the whole update of the atribute any time another article gets selected? Just saying cause to this point, I've been using pure PHP, no JS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally, I would put the price in the the original options:

```
<select id="article_select">
    <?php
        $article_group = article_search();
        foreach($article_group as $item) {
            echo "<option value=\"{$item["idArt"]}\" price=\"{$item['price']}\">{$item["name"]}</option>";
        }
    ?>  
</select>
```

Then, you can collect this using JQuery like so (http://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/6unsdztu/):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#article_select").change(function(){
        var price = $(this).find("option:selected").attr("price");
        var $inp = $('<input />',{
            type: "text",
            class: "details",
            id: "price_" + $(this).val(),
            name: "price",
            value: price
        });
        var $p = $('<p />');
        $p.append("<label>Price:</label>", $inp);
        $p.appendTo("#price_form");
    });
});
```

This seems like a bad idea overall. The user could try to manipulate the price if you're passing it back to the Database, unless they get a chance to negotiate the price.

Since the Price is in the DB, why bring it out to a text field? he end, if this is a shopping cart, we just need to know which items are in the cart, and we can calculate a total later or as we go. Hopefully the above example fits what you need. If not, comment or edit your post with more details.

Comment: you should use data- prefix for custom data attributes

Comment: I generally do not do this with JQuery. This helps avoid issue when porting code to be used with JQuery Mobile which uses `data-` attributes a lot.

Comment: Nice, that works! Thanks a lot.
Just one question: when I select a different article form the article_select, it creates a new price text. It would be better if instead of creating a new one, just updated the existing price text, otherwise the user could get at some point 20 different price texts.

Comment: You can do that. I would make the field static in the HTML, maybe hidden, and when a selection is made, it can be shown and updated with the price. If a 2nd article is selected, you would update the total.

Comment: Thanks again for the help ;)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you have a look at some Ajax tutorials first. But basically what you need to do is (requires Jquery):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //if the user selects another option from the select element
    $("#article_select").change(function(){
        data = "function=updatePrice&value="+$(this).val();
        loadAjax(data);
    });
})

//sends the data to the server. In the example above you can use the two
//variables 'function' and 'value' as normal post parameters. 
function loadAjax (data) {

        req = $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                encoding:"UTF-8",
                url: 'index.php',
                cache: false,
                data: data,
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                        alert("Error: "+thrownError);
                },
                xhr: function () {
                        var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
                        return xhr;
                },
                beforeSend: function () {

                },
                complete: function () {
                },
                success: function (response) {
                   response = $.parseJSON(response);
                   $("#price").val(response.price);
                }
        });
}
```

In your php code you can use the post variables and write a function like

```
if($_POST['function']=='updatePrice')
{
    $price = $model -> getPrice($_POST['value'])
}
```

which gets the price from your database.  You could then for example assign the price to a variable. E.g.

```
$content['price'] = $priceFromDatabase;
```

afterwards you have to json_encode this variable with

```
 return json_encode($this -> content);
```

Of course you should do some sanitizing before using the post variables to prevent SQL injection etc.

However I would normally also do it the way @Twisty suggested to prevent unnecessary load for your server. But if you wanna learn Ajax in general, this would be the way to do it.

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks for your help, though I'm using Twisty's answer